# Mutual SSL security mode binding configurations

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, mutual-authentication

I have two questions regarding the security mode regarding mutual ssl.

I have look through a few sites such as:

**1.**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication%20

**2.**https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348595/Use-Mutual-SSL-Authentication-in-WCF

In all the binding configurations. I realized that all security mode is set as **'Transport'**.

```
<bindings>  
      <wsHttpBinding>  
        <!-- configure wsHttp binding with Transport security mode and clientCredentialType as Certificate -->  
        <binding>  
          <security mode="Transport">  
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>              
          </security>  
        </binding>  
      </wsHttpBinding>  
 </bindings>
```

In regards to this, what I want to know is if its possible to use other kind of security mode such as 
**'Message'** or **'TransportWithMessageCredential'**. If so why?

Furthermore if its possible, does the client side have to change their security mode to the same as the server side?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft official document also offers an example of authenticating the client with message security mode with mutual certificates.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-mutual-certificates
What we need to do is configuring a service certificate on the server-side, a certificate on the client-side, also establishing the certificate trust relationship between the client-side and server-side.
Here is a standard configuration.

```
  <system.serviceModel>  
    <behaviors>  
      <serviceBehaviors>  
        <behavior name="serviceCredentialBehavior">  
          <serviceCredentials>  
            <serviceCertificate findValue="Contoso.com"   
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine"  
                                storeName="My"   
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />  
          </serviceCredentials>  
        </behavior>  
      </serviceBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>  
    <services>  
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceCredentialBehavior"   
               name="ServiceModel.Calculator">  
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/Calculator"   
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"  
                  bindingConfiguration="InteropCertificateBinding"  
                  name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"  
                  contract="ServiceModel.ICalculator" />  
      </service>  
    </services>  
    <bindings>  
      <wsHttpBinding>  
        <binding name="InteropCertificateBinding">  
          <security mode="Message">  
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"  
                     negotiateServiceCredential="false"  
                     establishSecurityContext="false" />  
          </security>  
        </binding>  
      </wsHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is also applicable to the `TransportWithMessageCredential` security mode. As long as the security mode is `Transport` security mode, we need to bind a certificate to the particular port.
Besides, the binding configuration should be coherent between the client-side and the server-side. Just like the service contract is shared between the client-side and the server-side.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.